# reutilização de Javascript entre sites hospedados em linux

Tags: javascript, linux

Antes de gastar energia tentando implementar isso, gostaria de saber se alguem sabe se isso é uma má prática e se realmente funciona

tenho alguns sites hospedados com a pasta root da seguinte maneira:

Site 1:
/var/www/site1/html/

Site 2:
/var/www/site2/html/

Site 3:
/var/www/site3/html/

tenho alguns arquivos JS que utilizo nos 3 sites, quando atualizo em um, preciso copiar para os outros (sim já tá fedendo demais essa situação)

minha dúvida é, posso colocar esses arquivos na pasta:

/var/www/

e nos sites colocar algo como:

```
<script src="../../arquivo.js"></script>
```

?

Comment: Sugestão: remova a tag `JavaScript` porque sua dúvida não tem a ver com isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende da sua configuração. Mas antes de mais nada é preciso lembrar que Javascript é interpretado pelo Navegador, portanto o script precisa estar acessível a todos pela web.

Se você define um site com a raiz na pasta `/var/www/site1/html/` e tenta acessar uma pasta em `/var/www/scripts` usando `../../scripts`, isso não deveria funcionar. Lembrando que o navegador abre pela web, portanto nem seria uma URL válida pois seria abaixo da raiz do domínio.

Se você simplesmente define seus sites em `/var/www` e acessa cada um com o nome da pasta na frente do domínio, funcionaria.

Acho que a pergunta que você tem que fazer é se faz sentido que isso fique estruturado assim. Querendo ou não esta pasta abaixo do root vai fazer parte da estrutura interna do seu site se você usar ela assim.

Os sites 1, 2, 3 tem alguma relação entre si ou somente compartilham essas bibliotecas javascript? E cada qual tem seu domínio?

Quais problemas novos essa config vai causar? (se for migrar por exemplo, já vai ser mais complicado).

Você poderia ter uma pasta de trabalho com os Javascript (onde você modifica eles) e ter um script de instalação (Bash ou Makefile) que copia/substitui os arquivos para os sites (todos ou somente um deles) e depois já seta permissões/usuario.

No caso usaria algo como `make site1` ou `make all` pra copiar.

Assim ainda ficaria o site todo contido dentro de sua pasta, mas ficaria fácil de atualizar. Penso que também ficaria mais fácil de testar essas libs antes de instalar em produção também.

De fato os scripts só precisam estar visíveis na web para sua página acessar. Mas usar scripts vindos de outros domínios costuma ser bloqueado pelos navegadores por razões de segurança.

Outra opção seria liberar o uso de links simbólicos (symlinks) no apache ou nginx. Por padrão essa opção costuma ficar desligada por questões de segurança, pois com isso ligado fica extremamente fácil de publicar/acessar qualquer pasta do servidor na Web.

Para evitar usar symlinks, pode-se usar hardlinks (links não simbólicos), que basicamente duplicam os arquivos, mas mantém o mesmo inode no disco. Assim os arquivos vão continuar únicos, mas vão possuir mais de uma referência na árvore do disco. Bem complexo de manter e normalmente não recomendável a não ser que tenha um motivo real pra isso.

O maior problema é manter um ponto de falha tão crítico para tantos sistemas.
Qualquer problema com essa pasta e todos os sites vão sofrer.
Trabalhar como repositório instalável evita todos esses problemas e ainda permite trabalhar mais tranquilo em um ambiente de testes.

Comment: E se eu usar um link simbólico?

Comment: Eu até ia sugerir symlink como opção, mas tanto apache quanto nginx normalmente precisam de configurações adicionais para que symlinks funcionem. Por padrão costuma ficar desligado isso. Além disso acaba abrindo mais uma vulnerabilidade no sistema pois fica fácil montar qualquer pasta do servidor na Web. Vou editar a resposta para incluir mais informações sobre isso.

Comment: Optei por usar scripts de instalação, deu certinho, fica mais trabalhoso mas pelomenos ficou mais fácil de colocar scripts testados em produção.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode rever sua estrutura de arquivos, como mencionado acima, mas eu sugiro algo mais simples. Aloque seus arquivos JavaScript em um domínio/subdomínio acessível na internet e vincule-os em seus projetos, da mesma forma que utilizamos bibliotecas através de CDNs. Assim você pode utilizar até em outros projetos fora deste servidor de forma segura. Ex.

Domínios:
www.meusite1.com.br
www.meusite2.com.br
www.meusite3.com.br

Endereço JS:
  js.nomegenerico.com.br/[seuscript].js

Obs: Se optar por fazer alterações na estrutura de pastas, cuidado com as permissões.